# Kdenlive: Rendering crashed with mlt_repository_init, producer_xml and GLib-GObject-CRITICAL errors

Tags: arch-linux, video, kdenlive

I am trying to render a Vertical HD 30 fps video with Kdenlive.

However, rendering crashes no matter what output format (GIF HQ, MP4-H264/AAC, MPEG-2, Matroska-H264/AAC, WebM-VP8/Vorbis) I choose.

The following errors are logged:

```
Rendering of […] crashed

mlt_repository_init: failed to dlopen /usr/lib/mlt/libmltopencv.so (libopencv_tracking.so.406: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
mlt_repository_init: failed to dlopen /usr/lib/mlt/libmltavformat.so (libavformat.so.59: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
mlt_repository_init: failed to dlopen /usr/lib/mlt/libmltvidstab.so (libvidstab.so.1.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
mlt_repository_init: failed to dlopen /usr/lib/mlt/libmltsdl.so (/usr/lib/mlt/libmltsdl.so: undefined symbol: XGetWindowAttributes)
(process:23596): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 21:24:12.079: cannot register existing type 'gtkmm__GBinding'
[producer_xml] Property without a service 'property'? [producer_xml] Property without a service 'property'?? [producer_xml] Property without a service 'property'? [producer_xml] Property without a service 'property'?? [producer_xml] Property without a service 'property'? [producer_xml] Property without a service 'property'?? [producer_xml] Property without a service 'property'? [producer_xml] Property without a service 'property'??
[producer_xml] Property without a service 'property'? [producer_xml] Property without a service 'property'?? [producer_xml] Property without a service 'property'? [producer_xml] Property without a service 'property'?? [producer_xml] Property without a service 'property'? [producer_xml] Property without a service 'property'?? [producer_xml] Property without a service 'property'? [producer_xml] Property without a service 'property'?? [producer_xml] Property without a service 'property'? [producer_xml] Property without a service 'property'?? [producer_xml] Property without a service 'property'? [producer_xml] Property without a service 'property'?? [producer_xml] Property without a service 'property'? [producer_xml] Property without a service 'property'?? [producer_xml] Property without a service 'property'?
[producer_xml] Property without a service 'property'?? [producer_xml] Property without a service 'property'? [producer_xml] Property without a service 'property'?? [producer_xml] Property without a service 'property'? [producer_xml] Property without a service 'property'?? [producer_xml] Property without a service 'property'? [producer_xml] Property without a service 'property'?? [producer_xml] Property without a service 'property'? [producer_xml] Property without a service 'property'?? [producer_xml] Property without a service 'property'? [producer_xml] Property without a service 'property'?? [producer_xml] Property without a service 'property'? [producer_xml] Property without a service 'property'?? [producer_xml] Property without a service 'property'? [producer_xml] Property without a service 'property'?? [producer_xml] Property without a service 'property'? [producer_xml] Property without a service 'property'?? [producer_xml] Property without a service 'property'?
[producer_xml] Property without a service 'property'?? [producer_xml] Property without a service 'property'? [producer_xml] Property without a service 'property'?? [producer_xml] Property without a service 'property'? [producer_xml] Property without a service 'property'?? [producer_xml] Property without a service 'property'? [producer_xml] Property without a service 'property'?? [producer_xml] Property without a service 'property'? [producer_xml] Property without a service 'property'?? [producer_xml] Property without a service 'property'? [producer_xml] Property without a service 'property'?? [producer_xml] Property without a service 'property'?
[producer_xml] Property without a service 'property'?? [producer_xml] Property without a service 'property'? [producer_xml] Property without a service 'property'?? [producer_xml] Property without a service 'property'? [producer_xml] Property without a service 'property'?? [producer_xml] Property without a service 'property'? [producer_xml] Property without a service 'property'?? [producer_xml] Property without a service 'property'?
[producer_xml] Property without a service 'property'?? [producer_xml] Property without a service 'property'? [producer_xml] Property without a service 'property'?? [producer_xml] Property without a service 'property'? [producer_xml] Property without a service 'property'?? [producer_xml] Property without a service 'property'?
[producer_xml] Property without a service 'property'?? [producer_xml] Property without a service 'property'? [producer_xml] Property without a service 'property'?? [producer_xml] Property without a service 'property'? [producer_xml] Property without a service 'property'?? [producer_xml] Property without a service 'property'? [producer_xml] Property without a service 'property'?? [producer_xml] Property without a service 'property'? [producer_xml] Property without a service 'property'?? [producer_xml] Property without a service 'property'? [producer_xml] Property without a service 'property'?? [producer_xml] Property without a service 'property'? [producer_xml] Property without a service 'property'?? [producer_xml] Property without a service 'property'? [producer_xml] Property without a service 'property'?? [producer_xml] Property without a service 'property'? [producer_xml] Property without a service 'property'??
[producer_xml] Property without a service 'property'? [producer_xml] Property without a service 'property'?? [producer_xml] Property without a service 'property'? [producer_xml] Property without a service 'property'?? [producer_xml] Property without a service 'property'? [producer_xml] Property without a service 'property'?? [producer_xml] Property without a service 'property'? [producer_xml] Property without a service 'property'?? [producer_xml] Property without a service 'property'? [producer_xml] Property without a service 'property'?? [producer_xml] Property without a service 'property'?
[producer_xml] Property without a service 'property'?? [producer_xml] Property without a service 'property'? [producer_xml] Property without a service 'property'?? [producer_xml] Property without a service 'property'? [producer_xml] Property without a service 'property'?? [producer_xml] Property without a service 'property'?
[producer_xml] Property without a service 'property'?? [producer_xml] Property without a service 'property'? [producer_xml] Property without a service 'property'?? [producer_xml] Property without a service 'property'? [producer_xml] Property without a service 'property'?? [producer_xml] Property without a service 'property'? [producer_xml] Property without a service 'property'??
[producer_xml] Property without a service 'property'? [producer_xml] Property without a service 'property'?? [producer_xml] Property without a service 'property'? [producer_xml] Property without a service 'property'?? [producer_xml] Property without a service 'property'? [producer_xml] Property without a service 'property'??
[producer_xml] Property without a service 'property'? [producer_xml] Property without a service 'property'?? [producer_xml] Property without a service 'property'? [producer_xml] Property without a service 'property'?? [producer_xml] Property without a service 'property'? [producer_xml] Property without a service 'property'??
[producer_xml] Property without a service 'property'? [producer_xml] Property without a service 'property'?? [producer_xml] Property without a service 'property'? [producer_xml] Property without a service 'property'?? [producer_xml] Property without a service 'property'?
[producer_xml] Property without a service 'property'?? [producer_xml] Property without a service 'property'? [producer_xml] Property without a service 'property'?? [producer_xml] Property without a service 'property'? [producer_xml] Property without a service 'property'?? [producer_xml] Property without a service 'property'?
[producer_xml] Property without a service 'property'?? [producer_xml] Property without a service 'property'? [producer_xml] Property without a service 'property'?? [producer_xml] Property without a service 'property'? [producer_xml] Property without a service 'property'?? [producer_xml] Property without a service 'property'?
[producer_xml] Property without a service 'property'?? [producer_xml] Property without a service 'property'? [producer_xml] Property without a service 'property'?? [producer_xml] Property without a service 'property'? [producer_xml] Property without a service 'property'?? [producer_xml] Property without a service 'property'? [producer_xml] Property without a service 'property'??
[producer_xml] Invalid state of playlist end 2
[producer_xml] Invalid state of playlist end 5
```

I am on Arch Linux (`6.3.8-arch1-1`).

The shared object files with the specific versions mentioned in the error log are indeed missing on my system:

```
$ ls /usr/lib/(libopencv_tracking|libavformat|libvidstab).so*
/usr/lib/libavformat.so@     /usr/lib/libavformat.so.58.76.100*  /usr/lib/libavformat.so.60.3.100*  /usr/lib/libopencv_tracking.so.407@    /usr/lib/libvidstab.so@
/usr/lib/libavformat.so.58@  /usr/lib/libavformat.so.60@         /usr/lib/libopencv_tracking.so@    /usr/lib/libopencv_tracking.so.4.7.0*  /usr/lib/libvidstab.so.1.2*
```

The following package versions are installed:

```
$ yay -Q kdenlive opencv ffmpeg ffmpeg4.4 mlt mlt6
kdenlive 23.04.2-1
opencv 4.7.0-12
ffmpeg 2:6.0-8
ffmpeg4.4 4.4.4-1
mlt 7.16.0-1
mlt6 6.26.1-10
```

I am not sure whether this is causing the rendering to crash (I am not using any OpenCV tracking for instance). I couldn't find any relevant information on the other errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uninstalling the `mlt6` package solved the issue.